# how to connect EC2 and mysql RDS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds, amazon-vpc

Gurus,
I am very new to AWS and all its services, I would like to know the best way to connect EC2 and RDS so they can talk to each other, while EC2 is on Public subnet and RDS is on a private subnet.

Thanks, gurus

Answer (score 0):

Everything in a VPC can "talk to" everything else in the VPC, regardless of public versus private subnets. You just need to edit the security group assigned to the RDS instance to allow connections from the security group assigned to the EC2 instance.